# Shared Preferences not saving data

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

Initializing highScore array :

```
 score = 0;
 sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("Scores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    //initialize the array of high scores
    highScore[0] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score1",0);
    highScore[1] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score2",0);
    highScore[2] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score3",0);
    highScore[3] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score4",0);
    highScore[4] = sharedPreferences.getInt("score5",0);
```

Checking For the 4 Highest Values :

```
highScore[5] = score;
Arrays.sort(highScore);
```

This is my code for saving data in shared preferences

```
SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedPreferences.edit();
                for(int j=4;j>=0;j--){
                    e.putInt("score"+(j+1),highScore[j]);
                    e.apply();
                }
```

Comment: Please check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024831/android-shared-preferences-example

Comment: is this the full code for saving value in the preferences?

Comment: Have you initialized the sharedPreferences with the key "Scores"?

Comment: Can you try using 
e.commit(); 
instead of 
e.apply();

Comment: @NakulSudhakar Apply is faster than commit. They have the same functionality.

Comment: @JDFuzyll : try logging this values `"score"+(j+1)`

Comment: try to debug your code, it will help.

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest to use like that.

```
SharedPreferences pref;
pref= context.getSharedPreferences("Scores", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor e = pref.edit();
            for(int j=4;j>=0;j--){
                e.putInt("score"+(j+1),highScore[i]);
            }
            e.apply();
```

Comment: My SharedPreferences object is public 
    

`public SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;`

Comment: @JDFuzyll Have you tried this? I would recommend loading the shared preferences object each time you go to use it. Not storing it globally.

Comment: Thanks a lot 

It did Work

Comment: Very Happy to help you. @JDFuzyll

Answer (score 0):

Instead of commiting after completing the if loop , commit in each iteration of your loop like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor e = sharedPreferences.edit();
                for(int j=4;j>=0;j--){
                    e.putInt("score"+(j+1),highScore[i]);
                              e.apply();
  }
```

it will work.